# Call Javascript function in Magento Form

Tags: admin, php, javascript

I have a Form in my Admin view with a small output "console".
I want to update the content of the Console, while the form is submitted.

So here's my outputform.phtml:

```
 <div class="entry-edit">
    <form id="edit_form" name="edit_form" method="post" action="<?=$this->getUrl('*/*/post')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

<input name="data" type="file" id="upload" value="UploadData"  accept="text/csv" />

<button onclick="check()" class="scalable save" type="button"><span> Send</span></button>





<!----- Output  Console ------------------->
<div style="height:130px; width:500px;overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;">
<table style="width:100%;" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2"  name="faultOutput">
</table>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

so after my form is submitted, the  postAction() Method is called in my Controller.php file.

```
 public function postAction()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        try {
            if (empty($post)) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Invalid form data.'));
            }
           catch(){}
         ..............
    }
```

Now i want to update the outputconsole of my outputform.phtml by calling a javascript function within the file. But how can i call it within the postAction() php method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will you please provide details - 1 - is this custom module or existing? 2- if this is custom module then at what is the location of your block files in Admin section? Please provide more details that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually this won't work. The PHP is all rendered ahead of time (i.e. before your user takes any action). To execute PHP code after the page is already loaded you would use AJAX to make an additional request. If you don't want to mess with any of that, you could just pop the results up in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

So this means, since I would pop the results up in a separate window, I wouldn't need to call a javascript function anymore, Thanks!

But still I don't really get how to put the results in my postAction() method in a separate window